# Change Sublime Text 2 Font Weight

Tags: sublimetext2, antialiasing

The normal font-weight in Sublime Text was always bold.

[image]

Now it is really thin and i cant work with that. Can I change it back to what it was before ?

[image]

I have not changed anything, it just changed after i rebooted my macbook.

Thanks,
Mottenmann

Comment: Is it Sublime or whole OSX as general? Might be OSX system-wide antialiasing settings. You can tune it from the command line if something has messed it up.

Comment: True, this looks like anti-aliasing issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. Sublime Text 2 suddenly changed to having a super thin font on my Mac.

Add

**Mac:**

```
"font_options":["no_round"],
```

**PC:**

```
"font_options":["bold"],
```

to

[image]

[image]

Comment: for my ST3, the solution was to remove `"gray_antialias"` from `font_options`.

Answer (score 12):

A simpler approach would be to simply add the weight name to the `font_face` (ie for medium use "Medium", for light use "Light", etc)

Before:

```
{
    "font_face": "Source Code Pro",
    "font_size": 16.0,
}
```

After:

```
{
    "font_face": "Source Code Pro Light",
    "font_size": 16.0,
}
```

The font "Source Code" comes in ExtraLight, Light, Medium, Regular, etc. And if you want use the Light version, appending the font-weight along with the font_face will work.

p.s. try Source Code Pro or Inconsolata. They are the best coding fonts till date.

Answer (score 1):

While your issue seems to be specifically anti-aliasing in your mac, you could modify your theme to make specific text show with different `fontStyle`.

For example, take the Monokai Theme. Use the `Preferences > Browse Packages` menu shortcut and see that in the Color Schemes folder you will have a Monokai.tmTheme file. Open and edit this file to make some text look italic.

For example, for comment text... look for (around line 48):

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comment</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>comment</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#75715E</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

To change font style to have it display in italics, add lines marked with asterisk:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comment</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>comment</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#75715E</string>
        *<key>fontStyle</key>   
        *<string>italic</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

For your desired effect, you would choose `bold` instead of `italics` for the fontStyle string.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this change on Sublime when I restarted my computer (Macbook Air, OSX 10.7) whilst being connected to an external monitor. 
To fix it, I did the following: Unplugged the external monitor, restarted Sublime, plugged monitor again.

Answer (score -1):

bypass alternative with:

use "font_face": "Bahnschrift Light",

instead **strong text** "font_face": "Bahnschrift",

some how:  its notworking with font-weight